# With OnsenUI how do I disable page scroll and pull-to-refresh when dragging on a graph element?

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui, dygraphs

I am creating an app using Cordova and OnsenUI. OnsenUI has a Pull-To-Refresh function. I am also displaying a graph using dygraphs. A user can pinch zoom the graph then drag the graph around to see different parts of the graph after it is zoomed in. However, once a users drags down on the graph, the graph moves but it also starts to active the pull-to-refresh. Also, if the users is using a small screen phone and you have to scroll down to see the graph, if they scroll the graph up, it causes the entire page to scroll up.

I am wondering how I can make the page scroll and pull-to-refresh not activate if the users is touching or moving (I believe 'touch' and 'touchmove') the graph, but once they stop touching the graph, the normal functionality of the page scroll and pull-to-refresh will work again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this considering that `ons-pull-hook` has a `disabled` attributed ([Documentation](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-pull-hook.html)).

Wrap your graph in a `div` element with `id="myGraph"` and set the `disabled` attribute when a touch action has been performed in the `div` element. Once the touch action ends, the `ons-pull-hook` should be enabled again.

Here is the code:

```js
ons.ready(function() {
  var graph = document.getElementById("myGraph");
  var pullHook = document.querySelector("ons-pull-hook");

  graph.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
    pullHook.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  });

  graph.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
    graph.removeAttribute("disbled");
  });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works great, however, once I touch the graph, and stop, then I try to pull-refresh it "freaks outs". The best way I can explain it is that it flashes and never lets the pull down fully happen. Any ideas?

Comment: So, after reading the documentation a bit further and taking your lead, I was able to get this to work 100%. The only difference is, instead of using `setAttribut` and `removeAttribute` I had to use `setDisabled(true)` and `setDisabled(false)`. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction!

Comment: The behavior should be the same, maybe there is a bug, but I agree that using `setDisabled` method is more appropriate and elegant. Glad it helped :)